# kivy language not handling enums?

Tags: python, enums, kivy-language

I have a file with constants, like this:

```
from enum import Enum
class Ear(Enum):
    LEFT = 0
    RIGHT = 1
```

Then I import it in a kv file like this:

```
#: import Ear vocelab.ark_const
```

And finally use it to set an ObjectProperty named "ear":

```
Audiogram:
    id: audiogram
    ear: Ear.LEFT
```

And then I get this error (well the traceback is very long, this is just a part of it):

```
kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "C:\Users\Laci\Python\Projects\VoceLab\vocelab\vocelab.kv", line 224:
 ...
     222:                            Audiogram:
     223:                                id: audiogram
 >>  224:                                ear: Ear.LEFT
     225:                    TabbedPanelItem:
     226:                        id: tp_devices
 ...
 BuilderException: Parser: File "C:\Users\Laci\Python\Projects\VoceLab\vocelab\vocelab.kv", line 224:
 ...
     222:                            Audiogram:
     223:                                id: audiogram
 >>  224:                                ear: Ear.LEFT
     225:                    TabbedPanelItem:
     226:                        id: tp_devices
 ...
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LEFT'
```

I think this may be a bug, or at least the error message if wrong. It says "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LEFT'" but "Ear" is not a module. I'm not sure about this but maybe kivy tries to get the "LEFT" attribute of the ark_consts module, instead of the enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have imported the module, not the class

try this:

```
#: import Ear vocelab.ark_const.Ear
```

the next of `import` in this is the name that you give to what you import, what you import is the last